# Pull the particular string from nvarchar type column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a string like `&hprop=anprop_p&asofmonth=01/2017&OutputType=PDF&IsGrid=-&ReportCode=AllCol1&Attach=NO&IsRequestQue=true` and want to pull the values partitioned by & from string.

As we see above each string is separated with & and both the values have a name i.e. `Outputtype=` and `ReportCode=`

In SQL query it should return only values in different columns. AllCol1 Aand PDF

I have tried the below query but it is pulling string ReportCode=AllCol1

```
declare @Str varchar(500)
select  SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX('&ReportCode=', @Str) + 1, LEN(@Str)), 0, CHARINDEX('&', SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX('&', @Str) +1, LEN(@Str))))
```

Comment: SQL Server's forté is not string manipulation. Honestly, you would be better with a different choice of language.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov : Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64)

Comment: A database column should not contain multiple values of the same kind. This violates principles of normalization, and may lead to a data integrity issues.  If this is still in development, please consider switching the storage of said column to another table with appropriate column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using SQL Server 2016, you can take advantage of [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to split your url into the component query parameters, e.g.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(N'&hprop=anprop_p&asofmonth=01/2017&OutputType=PDF&IsGrid=-&ReportCode=AllCol1&Attach=NO&IsRequestQue=true', '&');
```

Will return:

```
value
-----------------

hprop=anprop_p
asofmonth=01/2017
OutputType=PDF
IsGrid=-
ReportCode=AllCol1
Attach=NO
IsRequestQue=true
```

You would then need to split each result on `=` to separate it into the parameter name and the argument. e.g.

```
SELECT  s.value,
        Parameter = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('=', s.value) = 0 THEN s.value ELSE LEFT(s.value, CHARINDEX('=', s.value) - 1) END,
        Value = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('=', s.value) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(s.value, CHARINDEX('=', s.value) + 1, LEN(s.value)) END
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(N'&hprop=anprop_p&asofmonth=01/2017&OutputType=PDF&IsGrid=-&ReportCode=AllCol1&Attach=NO&IsRequestQue=true', '&') s;
```

Returns:

```
value               Parameter       Value
-------------------------------------------------
                    NULL
hprop=anprop_p      hprop           anprop_p
asofmonth=01/2017   asofmonth       01/2017
OutputType=PDF      OutputType      PDF
IsGrid=-            IsGrid          -
ReportCode=AllCol1  ReportCode      AllCol1
Attach=NO           Attach          NO
IsRequestQue=true   IsRequestQue    true
```

Finally, you would just need to extract the terms you are actually interested in, and PIVOT them to bring back one row. Bringing it all together, you get:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Col NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @T (Col) 
VALUES 
    (N'&hprop=anprop_p&asofmonth=01/2017&OutputType=PDF&IsGrid=-&ReportCode=AllCol1&Attach=NO&IsRequestQue=true'),
    (N'&hprop=anprop_p&asofmonth=01/2017&OutputType=XLS&IsGrid=-&ReportCode=AllCol3&Attach=NO&IsRequestQue=false');

SELECT  pvt.ID, pvt.OutputType, pvt.ReportCode
FROM    (   SELECT  T.ID,
                    t.Col,
                    Parameter = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('=', s.value) = 0 THEN s.value ELSE LEFT(s.value, CHARINDEX('=', s.value) - 1) END,
                    Value = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('=', s.value) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(s.value, CHARINDEX('=', s.value) + 1, LEN(s.value)) END
            FROM    @T AS t
                    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T.Col, '&') AS s
            WHERE   s.value <> ''
        ) AS t
        PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Parameter IN ([ReportCode], [OutputType])) AS pvt;
```

Which returns:

```
ID  OutputType  ReportCode
----------------------------------
1   PDF         AllCol1
2   XLS         AllCol3
```

**[Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ab449263183a4a3cda532eb19c02086b)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `string_split()`:

```
select max(case when s.value like 'Outputtype=%'
                then stuff(s.value, 1, 11, '')
           end) as Outputtype,
       max(case when s.value like 'ReportCode=%'
                then stuff(s.value, 1, 11, '')
           end) as ReportCode       
from string_split(@str, '&') s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e69e1152b7bab0f0a30b96896769d2a4) is a db<>fiddle.